# pushing an object giving me push not a function

Tags: javascript

been trying to debug for hours already been searrching but i cant get it .

```
  ratings = {
      "hotel_a": "2.8",
  };

   ///ratings.push ( { hotel_b : 3.2} );
  console.log(ratings);

   // total number of stars
  const starTotal = 5;

  for (const rating in ratings) {
      const starPercentage = (ratings[rating] / starTotal) * 100;
      const starPercentageRounded = `${(Math.round(starPercentage / 10) * 10)}%`;
      document.querySelector(`.${rating}.stars - inner`).style.width = starPercentageRounded;
  }
```

it gives me ratings.push is not a function.

Comment: Because `ratings` is an object and not an array.

Comment: how do i push an object?

Comment: @kenny You can't push. You can add more properties and values.

Comment: Either you use an array or you cannot use `.push()`. [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: ohhhh okayyy. thank youuuuu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
///ratings.push ( { hotel_b : 3.2} );
```

That wont work because `ratings` is an object and not array.

What you can do is create a new key and value.

```
ratings["hotel_b"] =3.2
```

or

```
ratings.hotel_b =3.2
```